# Having issues dealing with T(n) runtime problems

Tags: math, time, recurrence

I was going to meet with my TA today but just didn't have the time. I am in an algorithms analysis class and we started doing recurrence relations and I'm not 100% sure if I am doing this problem correct. I get to a point where I am just stuck and don't know what to do. Maybe I'm doing this wrong, who knows. The question doesn't care about upper or lower bounds, it just wants a theta.

The problem is this:

```
T(n) = T(n-1) + cn^(2)
```

This is what I have so far....

```
=T(n-2) + (n-1)^(2) + cn^(2)
=T(n-3) + (n-2)^(2) + 2cn^(2)
=T(n-4) + (n-3)^(2) + 3cn^(2)
```

So, at this point I was going to generalize and substitute K into the equation.

```
T(n-k) + (n-k+1)^(2) + c(K-1)^(2)
```

Now, I start to bring the base case of 1 into the picture. On a couple of previous, more simple problems, I was able to set my generalized k equation equal to 1 and then solve for K. Then put K back into the equation to get my ultimate answer.

But I am totally stuck on the (n-k+1)^(2) part. I mean, should I actually foil all this out? I did it and got k^(2)-2kn-2k+n^(2) +2n +1 = 1. At this point I'm thinking I totally must have done something wrong since I've never see this in previous problems.

Could anyone offer me some help with how to solve this one? I would greatly appreciate it.

Comment: You might try the folks over at [Computer Science](http://cs.stackexchange.com/) if you don't get good answers here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you have isn't fully correct even at the first line of "what I have so far".
Go ahead and do the full substitutions, to see that:

```
T(n-1) = T(n-2) + c(n-1)^2
```

so

```
T(n) = T(n-2) + c(n-1)^2 + c(n)^2
T(n) = T(n-3) + c(n-2)^2 + c(n-1)^2 + c(n)^2
```

Overall running time looks like adding "c(n-i)^2" for each value of i from 0 to your base case.  Hopefully that puts you on the right track.

Comment: Ohhhh, wow, okay I get what you're saying. I think I was trying to jump to conclusions a little too quickly. Thank you.

Comment: Okay, I went out as far as T(n-4) + c(n-3)^2+ c(n-2)^2 + c(n-1)^2 + cn^2. This almost reminds me of some weird factorial. But when I put K into things I end up back where I started with T(n-k) + c(n-(-k+1))^2 + c(k-1)^2. Maybe I'm totally missing some obvious point here which helps me simplify something I'm not aware of or possibly I'm doing something wrong.